# Azure Function GET sending: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

The project I'm on is using a Azure Functions as a servless API to manage data for an app. This was working completely fine until the company this is for had to revise the security of the function apps and the storage accounts. They ended up having to enacting a firewall with white list on the storage account and I had to upgrade the function apps to version ~2. All of this went well and then suddenly when calling a GET (whether it's using the test panel in portal.azure.com or Postman) on one of my function apps starting returning a

`You need to enable JavaScript to run this app`

and POST'S started returning a

`Status: 405 Method Not Allowed`

What configuration changes to the Function App, Storage Account, or anything else could make errors like this appear? I'm starting to think maybe AzureWebJobsStorage in the storage account has been deleted or malformed? And if thats the case what steps can be taken to remedy that? 
 
Here is the config to the function app (redacting any keys or identifiers):

```
[
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "~~~~~~~",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
    "value": "~~~~~~~",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "~~~~~~~",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~2",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "node",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
    "value": "~~~~~~~",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "~~~~~~~",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
    "value": "~10",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a botched proxy in the same function app. I used the /{*path} wild card and it was intercepting the API requests and sending them to the client.